# Azure Bot Service pricing

Tags: azure, botframework

1. Does anyone know if Azure Bot's Directline call to refresh token is free or will use the messaging quota? The free one has 10,000 messages/month and S1 package is RM$2.10 per 1,000 messages. This is because the token will expire after 30 minutes, and we want to auto refresh it before 30 minutes.
2. Does anyone know where to check the quota usage of the 10,000 messages? 
   In the Azure Portal's Web App Bot's Analytic page, it shows the number of activities, not sure if it is same as the 10,000 messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each activity is a message. From [this page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bot-service/):

> Bots communicate with the Bot Service channels by sending Activity
>   objects to the channel endpoint via HTTP POST, and by Activity objects
>   being sent to the Bot’s endpoint via HTTP POST. Each of these Activity
>   POSTs is a message.

1. No, they do not count. The calls to refresh the token are not activities, therefore not messages.
2. Yes, the analytics page is the correct place.

Comment: Thanks.                                                                                                                   
Is it a proper way to trigger a refresh, let says, every 20 minutes?                           We have the bot in a webpage.                                                                                
So, as long as the user has the page opened, the timer will refresh his token.                       
At the same time, we also refresh token on every activity.

Comment: Are you using the webchat embed? or Are you using the full webchat?

Comment: I'm doing a custom app, which uses a ASP.NET ashx to do a web request to the directline.

Comment: Yeah, you can implement whatever logic you want to accomplish the goal. You could do every 20 minutes, refresh on turn, or a more appropriate approach of keeping track of the last time a refresh was done and have logic to determine whether it was in a window that needs to refresh or not. [More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#refresh-token).